# How to add header to HttpWebRequest in Windows8 applicaition?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, httpwebrequest, microsoft-metro

I developing C#\XAML metro-ui application. I want to call some service and going to use `HttpWebRequest` for this. Previous realization of `HttpWebRequest` contains `ContentLength` and `UserAgent` properties. But realization for WinRT doesn't have it. I tried to use the approach described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7456544/182344). It works for `UserAgent` but not for `ContentLength`.
I've tried to set `Headers`

```
request.Headers["Content-length"] = Length;
request.Headers["User-agent"] = UserAgent;
```

But received the exception "The 'Content-length' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method."

Hot is it possible to set `Headers` in `HttpWebRequest` realized in WinRT?

Comment: If you remove setting content-length, does it work?  It's possible that the HttpWepRequest won't allow you to set content-length because it calculates it based on the content you're sending.

Comment: @LarryOsterman Nope. Moreover I need to set `Content-type` property. So I should comment it too. For approach described via link: I get `400 Bad Request` when I commented these properties. When I commented these for `HttpWebRequest` I get webexception `The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

Comment: Hmmm.  I can see HttpWebRequest blocking setting content-length (since it can calculate content-length). The bad request implies that there's something wrong with the message being sent, what does Fiddler show that you sent?

Comment: Here's a good article on how to get Fiddler working with a Metro style app http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/09/14/fiddler-and-windows-8-metro-style-applications-https-and-private-network-capabilities.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` has a semi-deprecated status under WinRT.  Some header values that could previously be modified on earlier .NET platforms can no longer cannot be modified with it.

It seems that [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28VS.110%29.aspx) is the new and improved replacement for HttpWebRequest with a simple API and full async support.

Since you want to specify Content-Length, I assume you're trying to POST or PUT something to the server.  In that case, you will want to use PostAsync() or PutAsync() as appropriate.

```
    var req = new HttpClient();
    req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-agent", UserAgent);
    req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-length", Length);
    return await req.PostAsync(RequestURL, Body);
```

You probably don't really need to specify the Content-length header, since it will be automatically included by those methods based on the actual length of the Body, but you can try it either way.

Comment: Yeah.. You are right.. Thanks for your answer. I'm playing with something like.. But as I can see `Body` is `HttpContent` type, right? And you put there your parameters, didn't you? Could you explain how did you put params in instance of `HttpContent`?

Comment: I found it. I've just encoded parameters string to `ASCII`. But it isn't complete solution. I mentioned in comment to @Larry Osterman that I had problem with setting `ContentType`. I found way to do it - 'content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");' Whatever, I marked you post as answer because you are pretty close to answer )