# Using specifig User-Agent and CookieContainer with WinRT

Tags: cookies, windows-runtime, user-agent

Is there any way to use CookieContainer and specify UserAgent in same request using WinRT?

Looks like HttpWebRequest does not support UserAgent.
Also HttpClient + HttpRequestMessage doesn't seem to support CookieContainer.

Or could I read received cookies from HttpRequestMessage somehow? (In WP7 cookies were not readable.)

Comment: This answer works for Silverlight, not WinRT.  There are two 
System.Net.Http.HttpClient class
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class
See http://www.unravelingcode.com/client-certificate-http-authentication-in-c-winrt-apps-part-1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to use CookieContainen with HttpClient also.
You just need to create first HttpClientHandler.
From there is it possible to add CookieContainer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh781241.aspx

> var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
>
> handler.CookieContainer = myCookieContainer;
>
> var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
>
> httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");

Comment: This answer works for Silverlight, not WinRT.  There are two 
System.Net.Http.HttpClient class
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient class
See http://www.unravelingcode.com/client-certificate-http-authentication-in-c-winrt-apps-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

New:

Here's an option that should work for User-Agent (and get on the road for cookies):

[How to add header to HttpWebRequest in Windows8 applicaition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960358/how-to-add-header-to-httpwebrequest-in-windows8-applicaition)

HttpClient is now the preferred way to do communication in WinRT.

Old:
You should be able to use the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. It has a [UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent.aspx) property and a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx). The cookie container web documentation has a example.

Comment: Yes documentation says I could. But code does not compile for Windows Store app. "Error 1 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a definition for 'UserAgent' and no extension method 'UserAgent' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Apparently, docs are still difficult to navigate for development specific to WinRT. :(  I've updated the answer.