# How can I set the Referer of a WebRequest

Tags: windows-runtime

I tried the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = ...
request.Headears["Referer"] = "http:.....";
```

But I get the following error:

```
The 'Referer' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
```

What is the approriate property or method?

HttpWebRequest does not have a Referer property.

Comment: Did you review - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.referer.aspx

Comment: Yes, but I am using WinRT...

Comment: Roger.  Take a look at the answer on this question, it may shed some light - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960358/how-to-add-header-to-httpwebrequest-in-windows8-applicaition