# Problems with the Freebase provider for F#

Tags: f#, freebase, f#-data

Hi i'm starting to create some code in f# to access freebase data. I have started following this tutorial  [freebase](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Understanding-the-World-with-F) but, even with the easiest test, it does not work, here you have an image:

The code: [image]

The Error: `System.ArgumentException: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name` [image]

Does anybody now what I'm doing wrong? Is this FSharp.Data ready for production? Thanks!

Comment: Rather than an image, the text of the error message would be a lot more useful...

Comment: "System.ArgumentException: The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on glancing at the source of [this file](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Net/Http.fs) it looks like some framework versions have a `UserAgent` property on `HttpWebRequest` but some don't, and the library you're using is assuming that your version of the framework doesn't when really it does.  Perhaps try referencing one of the non-portable versions of the library?

Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454301/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-user-agent-for-a-winrt-httpwebrequest) it looks like this might be an intentional limitation when targeting the RT version of the framework (you would need to use `HttpClient` instead of a traditional web request if you want to set the user agent), in which case this is a bug in the type provider implementation.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda Was this a bug in F# Data? If so, could you submit a pull request with fix, or record an issue what needs to be fixed?

Comment: Hi Tomas, it seems, as @kvb answered, the portable library doesn't work properly. I think it's a bug in Fsharp.Data because the portable library should work also in a normal WPF project. Can you provide me a link on where to record the issue?

Comment: @TomasPetricek - the issue seems to be that WinRT doesn't support setting the user agent on an `HttpWebRequest` (neither via a `UserAgent` property nor directly via the collection of headers).  The easy fix is to just remove the line setting the UA from the source file linked from my answer.  A more involved fix would be to use the portable `HttpClient` library instead.  It depends on how strongly you feel about the necessity of using a custom UA.

Comment: HttpClient unfortunately doesn't give us much, it's just a wrapper over HttpWebRequest. I tried to switch to it earlier but it caused more problems than it solved. Not sending any UA also is problematic, that's why I added it recently. This is fixable, I'll have a look at it soon: https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/542

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed in F# Data 2.0.5. You can you use any of the 3 versions on FSI without problems now.