# can not set restricted headers e.g. UserAgent in WebRequest for PCL

Tags: http-headers, mvvmcross, webrequest

microsoft did not implement it, and will not do so according to this:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770104/cannot-set-useragent-of-a-httpwebrequest-in-portable-class-and-winrt-libraries
But the web site I'm trying to get response from requires User-Agent header specified in the request, otherwise the response is wrong.
I am limited to using portable class library (PCL), since I'm working on mvvmcross cross platform project.
What is the best way to make such a web request?

Comment: You can define the interface in your PCL and then implement the code required to do user agent headers in your platform specific code

Comment: thank you, but can you give some code examples or point to an article?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454301/is-it-possible-to-modify-the-user-agent-for-a-winrt-httpwebrequest how about this?

Comment: I'm reading about dependency injection, probably that is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was trying to point you to in my first comment, Dependency Injection is the best way to go about this.  Here is a simple example from the MvvmCross documentation https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control#1-pcl-interface-with-platform-specific-implementation